# cx_oracle return question marks for hebrew characters

Tags: cx-oracle

I have a table with hebrew characters.
I run a select command and get ??? instead of the hebrew result.

I connect using python3 on linux redhat8 and cx_Oracle using enconding='UTF-8'.

the string in the table is hebrew, I can see it correctly from pl/sql on windows.

how can I fix this
Thanks you
Tsvi

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a discrepancy between the character set the database thinks the data is in and the actual character set of the data. This is covered in the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html).

Check the database character set using this SQL:

```
SELECT value AS db_charset
FROM nls_database_parameters
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

Check the client character set using this SQL:

```
select distinct client_charset
from v$session_connect_info
where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'SID')
```

Check the client character set both where it is working correctly (PL/SQL on Windows) and not working correctly (Python on Linux). If this doesn't help you figure it out, post the results in your question and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.